# character string from R as HTML in JS()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, r, datatables

I'm trying to make a datatable object that has a child table with each row.  I'm following the format of a [Child Rows](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/002-rowdetails.html) example given by Yihui Xie.

The example shows how to pass a simple string in, and I can even do rudimentary tables.  But I don't want to hardcode a lot of HTML, since R has great facilities to write HTML for me.

My problem is that if I user R to generate an character string as HTML, when I pass it into the datatable object through `JS`, it reads it as literal text instead of rendering it as HTML.

I'm sure it's a simple solution, but using `htmltools::htmlPreserve` and `htmltools::HTML` don't change anything, and I suspect I'll have to do something within the javascript.

```
DT::datatable({
    mtcars$rows <- 
      paste0("<tr><td>Gas Mileage</td><td>", mtcars$mpg, "</td></tr>",
             "<tr><td>Quarter Mile</td><td>", mtcars$qsec, "</td></tr>")
    cbind(' ' = '&oplus;', mtcars)
  },
  escape = c(-2, -13),
  selection = "single",
  options = list(
    columnDefs = list(
      list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(0, 13)),
      list(orderable = FALSE, className = 'details-control', targets = 1)
      )
    ),
  callback = JS("
    table.column(1).nodes().to$().css({cursor: 'pointer'});
    var format = function(d) {
      return '<table>' + 
             '<tr><td>Variable</td><td>Value</td></tr>' + 
             d[13] + 
             '</table>';
    };
    table.on('click', 'td.details-control', function() {
      var td = $(this), row = table.row(td.closest('tr'));
      if (row.child.isShown()) {
        row.child.hide();
        td.html('&oplus;');
      } else {
        row.child(format(row.data())).show();
        td.html('&CircleMinus;');
      }
    });"
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Try replacing `escape = c(-2, -13)` with [`escape = FALSE`](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/#escaping-table-content).

Comment: Yep, that was really simple.  This is my RTFM moment for the day.  The `escape` argument takes R indexes (starting at 1), and the `columnDefs` and `callback` take javascript indexes (starting at 0).  Your suggestion got me thinking about that difference.  If I change it to `escape = c(-2, -14)`, it works just as well as with `escape = FALSE`.

Comment: ah, nice! I understand the `-2` part. But how did you get the `-14`?

Comment: 'mtcars' has 11 columns.  I prepended the `&oplus;`es, and then `datatable` prepended the row names.  That makes the row names column 1, `&oplus` column 2, and `mtcars` takes columns 3 - 13.  My HTML code is tacked onto the end of `mtcars`, making 14 columns total.  The two columns with HTML are columns 2 and 14 (by R indexing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing `escape = c(-2, -13)` with [`escape = FALSE`](http://rstudio.github.io/DT/#escaping-table-content).

---

Looking at [the source code](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/datatables.R), the `escape` variable is passed into the `escapeData` function of `datatables` which [looks like this](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/blob/master/R/datatables.R). Hopefully it'll give you a bit of guidance as to how to correctly custom-specify what should/shouldn't be escaped. :)

```
# `i` here is your `escape` variable which can be either TRUE/FALSE, 
# indices, or colnames.
escapeData = function(data, i, colnames) {
  if (is.null(data) || prod(dim(data)) == 0 || identical(i, FALSE)) return(data)

  // see below for definition of convertIdx
  i = convertIdx(i, colnames, ncol(data))
  # only escape character columns (no need to escape numeric or logical columns)
  data[i] = lapply(data[i], function(x) {
    if (is.character(x) || is.factor(x)) htmlEscape(x) else x
  })
  data
}


# convertIdx looks like this: 
# convert character indices to numeric
convertIdx = function(i, names, n = length(names), invert = FALSE) {
  if (!is.character(i)) return({
    if (invert) {
      if (is.numeric(i)) -i else if (is.logical(i)) !i else {
        stop('Indices must be either character, numeric, or logical')
      }
    } else i
  })
  if (is.null(names)) stop('The data must have column names')
  o = setNames(seq_len(n), names)
  i = o[i]
  if (any(is.na(i)))
    stop("Some column names in the 'escape' argument not found in data")
  if (invert) o[-i] else i
}
```